# How to setup Linux machine to act as a Router

Tags: bash, scripts, iptables, router, traffic

How to setup Linux machine to act as a Router which is responsible for distributing internet traffic to other devices connected to switch. I want to use this scenario in order to assign Ip-based Bandwidth limit to each nodes connected to switch (Traffic Shaping). i mean instead of using taffic shaping tools or physical Router Device i want to use linux kernel.

Comment: You can implement the router and firewall functions with [iptables](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/iptables.8.html) and traffic control with [tc](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/tc.8.html).

Comment: @DougSmythies I'd suggest making a detailed answer explaining how that works.  If youd on't, I will 'cause I have such a 'router' in place on my singular subnet for test labs.

Comment: @ThomasWard : While my main gateway/router/firewall is a linux iptables based server, I have never actually used tc (been meaning to). Go ahead with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using a protocol suite called [Quagga](https://www.quagga.net/), installing it on Linux gives you a command prompt that resembles that of Cisco routers.

I have used this in one of [my projects](https://github.com/Hasan-Alsulaiman/my-work), I am using a network emulator called Mininet which you may not need, but you can follow the same installation instructions that I provide in the repo.

As for the traffic-shaping part, you can look into using an SDN for that, but I am not sure about how you would set it up.